# can the llvm interpreter handle the c++ exception?

Tags: c++, exception, llvm, interpreter

My source code is like this:

**test.cpp:**

```
void func(){
   throw "abc";
}

int main(){
try{
   func();
}

catch(...){
}
}
```

1. I compiled the code with `clang`

   ```
   clang -S -emit-llvm test.cpp
   ```
2. then excuted it with the `lli`:

   ```
   lli -force-interpreter test.ll
   ```

and then crashed:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type `char const*`

I am working with a macbook(llvm3.6).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes.

- compile C++ code with `clang++` instead of `clang`
- remove option `-force-interpreter`
- add option [-jit-enable-eh](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/lli.html)

I've modified a little your test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(){
       throw "test";
}

int main(){
    try{
           func();
    }

    catch(...){
        printf("Gotcha\n");
    }
}
```

*Result:*

> $clang++ -S -emit-llvm test.cpp
>   $lli -jit-enable-eh   test.ll
>   Gotcha